# open link in new window razor if checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to give my users the option to open links in a new window or in the same based on a checkbox value.  If the value is checked, then open in a new window, if not open in the same.  I would like to not have to reload the page when the selection is made if possible.

Comment: sounds like a question for javascript!

Comment: @DanielA.White did I forget to tag it as such?  Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`target`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_target.asp) link property.

```js
function setLinkTarget(checkbox, selector) {
  var link = document.querySelector(selector);
  if (link) {
    link.target = checkbox.checked ? '_blank' : '_self';
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" id="my-link">link</a>
<input type="checkbox" onClick="setLinkTarget(this, '#my-link')">
```

The [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7KJ9mpBkbBBLbj99LMRs).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript/Jquery - This is a way using jquery to see if a checkbox is checked or not and depending on that have two different anchor tags that will open in a new tab or same tab.

```
//Animated Checkbox
//Start by showing the open in same tab link
var b;
b = '<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self">Open In Same    Tab</a>'
document.getElementById('samelink').innerHTML = b;

$("#samelink").show();
$("#link").hide(); 


//Check if the checkbox was clicked or checked
$('#check').click(function() {
//If it is create the anchor tag and substitute it into the html
if(document.getElementById('check').checked) {

var c;
c = '<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Open In New Tab</a>'
document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = c;

$("#samelink").hide();
$("#link").show();
} else {
//If it hasn't been checked keep the open in same tab link in there
var b;
b = '<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self">Open In Same Tab</a>'
document.getElementById('samelink').innerHTML = b;

$("#samelink").show();
$("#link").hide();
}
});
```

HTML portion

```
<!-- Create the form -->
<div class="checkbox">
<form>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="check" class="checkb"><span class="label-text">Open in new window?</span></input>
</label>

</form>

<div class="linked">
<p id="link"></p><!-- if open in new tab is true put the link in this p tag, else put the link in the samelink p tag-->
<p id="samelink"></p>
</div>

</div>
```